# How To check Platform for OneSignal Push Notifications

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, onesignal

I'm using Ionic to add iOS and Android Push notifications.

I have it working for iOS, but I'm not sure how to initialize using Android. Every time I enter the ID with the firebase ID, it gives me an error. Do I need to double initialize?

Code:

**iOS**

```
  this.oneSignal.startInit('3234fwfe-923s-4fb2-23r3-723r3ef32');
```

How would I initialize the android/Firebase code as well? It gives me an error when I put in the parentheses above

***Android/Firebase***
 Is this Best practice?

```
this.oneSignal.startInit('ucsgi232-2322-fwe1-few4-wfefw232rff3','123456789011 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Platform and then select initialize method:

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';


constructor(private oneSignal: OneSignal,
        private platform: Platform) { }

initializeOneSignal() {
....

 if (this.platform.is('android')) {
     this.oneSignal.startInit('ucsgi232-2322-fwe1-few4-wfefw232rff3', '123456789011');
    }
    else {
        this.oneSignal.startInit('3234fwfe-923s-4fb2-23r3-723r3ef32');
    }
.....
 }
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't play to the platforms. Thank you!